# how to close menu when click outside it

Tags: jquery

I have a drop down menu and I want the behaviour such that when clicked outside the menu, it closes.

This is my jQuery code:

```
        <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $(".a-for-noti-scroll").on("click",function(){
          $("#nano").toggleClass("x");
          $(".top-triangle-noti-scroll").toggleClass("y");
          e.stopPropagation();
      });
      $("body").on("click",function(e){
          $('#nano').css('visibility', 'hidden');
          $(".top-triangle-noti-scroll").css('display', 'none');
          e.stopPropagation();
      });   
    });
    </script>
```

But this doesn't work.

I tried `.hide()` for the `body`, but in this way the menu does not open.
What should I do?

Comment: Try using $(document).on("click"

Comment: And make sure you add `e` as an argument (`..."click", function(e){...`).

Comment: dear friend it's not work, I add document instead body and add e, but not work

Comment: group them in separate divs or section. Separate them and then try again.

Comment: what you mean? I don't understand

Answer (score 0):

you may have a logical fault, try like this example:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  // click inside will leave it open
  $("#noti").on("click",function(e){
      $('#noti').css('display','block');
      e.stopPropagation();
  });

  // just for this example to open the "menu"
  $("#top").on("click",function(e){
      $("#noti").css('display','block');
      e.stopPropagation();
  });

  // any click around closes
  $(document).on("click",function(e){
      $('#noti').css('display', 'none');
      e.stopPropagation();
  });   
});
```

here is a [working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x7nLo1tf/)

This is an example only for the clickhandler stacking.

Comment: what you mean logical fault?